# How to optimize Monaco Editor with React and Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor

I could make it run using **react-monaco-editor** and Webpack 4.
Just adding the MonacoWebpackPlugin did the trick.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to optimise the config for Monaco Editor.
I'm going to use just JS code inside of it and I would like to use just the files for this language.

Looking into the **webpack-bundle-analyser**, Monaco's files have around 10MB, which is a looot! Also, it loads TS, CSS, JSON, etc.

My code so far:

```
// Webpack plugin config
new MonacoWebpackPlugin();

// Monaco editor options
const options = {
    automaticLayout: false,
    cursorStyle: 'line',
    fontSize: '14px',
    glyphMargin: true,
    lineHeight: '16px',
    readOnly: false,
    renderLineHighlight: 'none',
    roundedSelection: false,
    selectOnLineNumbers: false,
    minimap: {
        enabled: false,
    },
};

// My Component
<MonacoEditor
    language="javascript"
    options={options}
    value="// type your code here"
    onChange={(newValue, e) => console.log('on change monaco editor', newValue)}
    editorDidMount={(editor, monaco) => console.log('monaco editor did mount')}
/>
```

To understand better Monaco environment, I'm trying to look into its documentation, but to be honest, it's not that simple.
[Monaco Editor Documentation API](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html)

And also, [react-monaco-editor GitHub project](https://github.com/superRaytin/react-monaco-editor)

Therefore, I would like to ask what direction do I need to go?

Thanks!

Comment: `MonacoWebpackPlugin` should be used in a webpack configuration, not in a source file as your question implies.

Comment: Reading your question further, I suggest you first understand how to correctly use `monaco-editor` BEFORE thinking about optimising a generated webpack bundle size.

Comment: Thanks @Peter! I will do that!

Comment: @ItaloBorges Hey were u able to find solution for this?